# How to manipulate a payload in a REST API?

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, rest

This is my first webservice and I am still understanding POST's GET's etc. I have been working on a Spring REST service. What I am confused about is how do I deal with a payload sent by another application?

Basically I have one app sending a json payload to my Spring REST API and I want to be able to grab the values of each key and store them in an object

Here is basically my code so far:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    Payload payload;
    Item item;
    // gets the payload
    @RequestMapping(value = "/buildevents/get-job", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity <Payload> get() {
        payload = new Payload();
        payload.setJobName("Testing");
        payload.setProjectName("Testing2");
        payload.setUserName("Me");
        payload.setPassWord("pass");
        return new ResponseEntity<Payload>(payload, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "buildevents/create-item", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity <Item> createItem(@RequestBody Item item) {

        item.setProject(" ");
        item.setItemName(payload.getJobName());
        item.setUserName(" ");
        item.setPassWord(" ");
        return new ResponseEntity<Item>(item, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I want to do GET'S and POST'S from this code. The info I need to do so will come from a json payload POST to this service though, so I need to store the info from it in my object's setters. I don't know if I'm going about this wrong, but I'm lost.

Comment: For a start your controller is stateful, so be aware when using the app. but you should read up on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters essentially you can just bind the payload to an entitiy without doing it yourself.

Comment: check this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. Try to compare your controller with the one in the guide.  If it fails, try starting from scratch using the guide.

Comment: @Darren Forsythe 
Thanks, it is supposed to be stateful for what I need.

Comment: @qtips
I'll see what I can do with that.